# WRONGTYPE exception when trying to set string in map (jedis)

Tags: java, string, exception, redis, jedis

I am getting a JedisDataException when trying to set a string as a value, and I can't seem to figure out where I am doing a mistake, if I am doing one at all. The Jedis version is 2.9.0 (I believe it is the latest).

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:127) ~[?:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:161) ~[?:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:215) ~[?:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:340) ~[?:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getIntegerReply(Connection.java:265) ~[?:?]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.hset(Jedis.java:658) ~[?:?]
    at net.ferskfisk.lobby.database.mongodb.Mongo$3.run(Mongo.java:174) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:71) ~[1.12.jar:git-Spigot-3d850ec-809c399]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.scheduler.CraftAsyncTask.run(CraftAsyncTask.java:52) [1.12.jar:git-Spigot-3d850ec-809c399]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]

                String name = "name";
                String string = "test";
                Jedis jedis = null;
                try {
                    jedis = Database.getInstance().getRedis().getJedisPool().getResource();
                    jedis.auth("password");
                    jedis.hset(name, "doc", string);
                } finally {
                    if(jedis != null)
                        jedis.close();
                }
```

Comment: The full stack-trace please, to see which variable is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a stacktrace, the most likely explanation is that you already have a key named `name` and it's not a hash.

Comment: I updated the post with the stacktrace :) There are no other variables than those you see here.